# Predict Future values Using LSTM

Tags: python, data-science, predict

I have dataset with data from 2019 to 2022, and I want to predict values for the years 2023 to 2025

```
2019-01-31      11286

2019-02-29      11182
        
2022-07-31      11286
2022-08-31      11182
2022-09-30      12023
2022-10-31      33200
2022-11-30      31228
```

Calling `df.info()` outputs the following:

```
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 1430 entries, 0 to 1429
 #   Column       Non-Null Count  Dtype 
---  ------       --------------  ----- 

 0   Date         1430 non-null   object
 1  Sales        1430 non-null   int64
```

I have tried with this code :

```
from pandas.tseries.offsets import DateOffset
future_dates=[df.index[-1]+ DateOffset(months=x)for x in range(0,24)]

error: TypeError
Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [44], in <cell line: 2>()
      1 from pandas.tseries.offsets import DateOffset
----> 2 future_dates=[df.index[-1]+ DateOffset(months=x)for x in range(0,24)]
TypeError: 'int' object is not callable****
```

output should be [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sjvpr.png)

Also tried  this code:

```
from pandas.tseries.offsets import DateOffset
future_dates=[df.index[-1] + DateOffset(months=x,days = y ,hours = z)for x in range(0,12) for y in range(1,32) for z in range(0,24)] 
future_datest_df=pd.DataFrame(index=future_dates[1:],columns=df.columns)
```

still same error

Comment: Welcome to SO! The question needs editing as it's difficult to get to the problem because of the current formatting - please see [How do I format my code blocks?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251361/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks) and update your question using [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/74937376/edit) option.

Comment: Don't base you question on links. All info should be visible here. Links are for documentation, libraries. Questions and answers should be readable without clicking on them.

Answer (score 0):

I think you didnt change your date in datetime format thats why its throwing value
So just use this

`df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])`

use above code before Dateoffset code
now your code gonna work

Comment: Thanks for helping . Actually I have changed  date column to datetime format.

Comment: Did you set `df['dates']` as index?

Comment: yes, my original  dataset is date wise and I have aggregated to monthly average sales using this code:

df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])
# Set the date as index 
df.set_index('Date',inplace=True)

# Select the proper time period for monthly aggreagation
df = df['2019-01-01':'2022-11-30'].resample('M').sum()
df.head()